# WebApi 2: What parameter type to expect in ApiController action for Associative Arrays

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, asp.net-web-api2

I'm receiving a get request like this:

```
myserver.com/api/UserApi?current=1&rowCount=10&sort[UserName]=asc&searchPhrase=John&id=265447
```

I implemented my api controller action like this:

```
public class UserApiController : ApiController
{

    public IEnumerable<UserViewModel> Get(int current, int rowCount, Dictionary<string,string> sort, string searchPhrase, int id)
    {
        // get users based on parameters...
    }

}
```

I tried declaring it as a `List<CustomType>` where `CustomType` has two string properties, as suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949857/passing-an-associative-array-using-json-which-type-to-expect-in-the-controller), but no success.

When I'm debugging, all parameters are passed properly, except this `sort` which looks like an associative array. I even tried declaring it as object, but it keeps coming null. Changing the url request is not an option, since I'm not the requester and I can't ask them to change the request format.

Even though I can't change the Url format for request, I can determine if it's coming as GET or POST requests. The options I tried with both methods (of course renaming my ApiController action method name from Get to Post).

What type should I expect, or how could I solve this?